# Pagination not display in magento advance search

Tags: php, magento

I have issue of Pagination and Filter in advance search page otherwise filter and pagination will works perfectly in other pages like search, category and subcategory. I don't why it's not working into advance search page.

Working URL : 
http://homefurnituretrading.co.uk/index.php/bedroom-furniture/wooden-beds.html

Not Working URL:
http://homefurnituretrading.co.uk/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer[]=164

Answer (score 0):

you have not added handle  catalogsearch_advanced_result for layered navigation.

open your catalog.xml file then find catalog_category_view this is handle for category page and you will find whithin reference left  block that is layered navigation.

so you need to add  left block in following layout handle

```
<catalogsearch_advanced_result>
  <reference name="left">
      <!-- add block here which you found in handle catalog_category_view -->
  </reference>
</catalogsearch_advanced_result>
```